# Locate sequential id blocks in SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that contains a list of numbers. Looks like the following:

```
1
2
3
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
18
19
```

I need to turn these into blocks that have sequential ids. For example,

```
1-3 
8-9 
11-15 
18-19
```

Is this possible using just SQL, or do I need to loop through and compare previous with current...

Comment: With SQLite you'll probably need to do that using a loop in your programming language

Comment: I think I can use this:  http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/81418-sql-query-find-block-seq\
uential-numbers

Comment: If the SQL Server solution works on SQLite, sure.

Comment: I think it will work but is not scalable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using temporary tables.

First we have to identify start- and endpoints:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fdc26/13

```
SELECT
  a.x AS ax,
  CASE WHEN p.x IS NULL THEN 1
       WHEN n.x IS NULL THEN 2
       ELSE                  0
  END AS begin_or_end
FROM       num AS a
LEFT  JOIN num AS n ON a.x + 1 = n.x /* n: next */
LEFT  JOIN num AS p ON a.x - 1 = p.x /* p: prev */
WHERE p.x IS NULL
   OR n.x IS NULL
ORDER BY a.x ASC;
```

Alternatively, you could split this into two queries:

```
SELECT a.x AS begin_point
FROM       num AS a
LEFT  JOIN num AS p ON a.x - 1 = p.x /* p: prev */
WHERE p.x IS NULL
ORDER BY a.x ASC;

SELECT a.x AS end_point
FROM       num AS a
LEFT  JOIN num AS n ON a.x + 1 = n.x /* n: next */
WHERE n.x IS NULL
ORDER BY a.x ASC;
```

I chose the first option for creating a temp table called `lohi` in my example.
I use the fact that every table has an automatic `rowid` (see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html / ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY for more detail)

The final query:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/21770/1

```
SELECT lo.ax, hi.ax
FROM       lohi AS lo
INNER JOIN lohi AS hi ON lo.rowid+1 = hi.rowid
WHERE lo.rowid % 2;
```

Comment: There is a single query solution: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1680#76